# Can we reduce pitch of a lead screw to reduce backlash of the lead screw?

Tags: motion, gearing, linear-bearing

In gear design, the backlash is introduced in the design itself (not by tolerances of manufacturing) to allow free meshing of the gears. The backlash in the design can be minimized by reducing the pitch of the gears. For example, If the pitch of a gear is halved the designed backlash can also be halved. Though the reduced pitch also reduces the torque capacity of the gear. Similarly, is it possible to reduce the pitch of the lead screw to reduce the backlash in the design?

Comment: of course it is possible to reduce the pitch of a lead screw ... but it is unclear what you are actually asking ... is the question about the pitch? `is it ok to reduce the thread pitch if we want to reduce backlash?` ... or is the question about the backlash? `will backlash be reduced if we reduce the thread pitch?`

Comment: @jsotal can the backlash be reduced by reducing the pitch?

Comment: That's interesting, because in my experience working with mechanical engineers, some of the backlash is designed in to account for manufacturing variations, and lower-backlash geartrains can be accomplished -- to a point -- with higher precision gears.

Comment: Have you looked at low-backlash leadscrew nuts, and at recirculating-ball leadscrews?